# Choosing best time series model at run time for multiple time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, model-selection, real-time

I am using methods from R `forecast` package to forecast revenue for 20,000 sectors. How to choose best time series model for each sector at run time?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *at run time*?

Comment: I mean dynamically. Different models (STLF, ARIMA) works better for different time series in my case. So can I iterate through each time series and fit using multiple models,  choose the one with less RMSE ?

Comment: Dynamically in time or across the series? (I would not call applying different models to different series somehow *dynamic*, I do not think this would be standard terminology.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `auto.arima` function from the said package, which is an algorithm for producing "best" ARIMA parametrized models in automatized way. You can read about the authors and their method after looking in help for this function.

It has some constraints though, so may not be super human.